# How to Modify this JSON array calling?

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to make a quiz app with already made project.

I have two layout files and two java class files. In this splash screen screen directly loads into the quiz page and load questions from a file "questions.txt" in the 'raw' folder in res.

**Splash Screen Activity class file.(QuizFunActivity.java)**

```
package ssk.quizfun;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class QuizFunActivity extends Activity{
    Intent menu = null;
    BufferedReader bReader = null;
    static JSONArray quesList = null;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3*1000);
                    finish();
                    loadQuestions();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizFunActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
                    QuizFunActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                } 
            }
        };
        thread.start();

     }

    private void loadQuestions() throws Exception {
        try {
        InputStream questions = this.getBaseContext().getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
        bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(questions));
        StringBuilder quesString = new StringBuilder();
        String aJsonLine = null;
        while ((aJsonLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            quesString.append(aJsonLine);
        }
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), quesString.toString());
        JSONObject quesObj = new JSONObject(quesString.toString());
        quesList = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions");
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                "Num Questions " + quesList.length());
        } catch (Exception e){

        } finally {
            try {
                bReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
            }

        }


    }

    public static JSONArray getQuesList() {
        return quesList;
    }

}
```

**Quiz Activity Java class(QuestionActivity.java)**

```
package ssk.quizfun;


import java.util.Arrays;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;

import android.view.View;
import android.util.Log;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    EditText question = null;
    RadioButton answer1 = null;
    RadioButton answer2 = null;
    RadioButton answer3 = null;
    RadioButton answer4 = null;
    RadioGroup answers = null;
    Button finish = null;
    int selectedAnswer = -1;
    int quesIndex = 0;
    int numEvents = 0;
    int selected[] = null;
    int correctAns[] = null;
    boolean review =false;
    Button prev, next = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);

        TableLayout quizLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.quizLayout);
        quizLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);

        try {
            question = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question);
            answer1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a0);
            answer2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a1);
            answer3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a2);
            answer4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a3);
            answers = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answers);
            RadioGroup questionLayout = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.answers);
            Button finish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.finish);
            finish.setOnClickListener(finishListener);

            prev = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Prev);
            prev.setOnClickListener(prevListener);
            next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next);
            next.setOnClickListener(nextListener);


            selected = new int[QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()];
            java.util.Arrays.fill(selected, -1);
            correctAns = new int[QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()];
            java.util.Arrays.fill(correctAns, -1);


            this.showQuestion(0,review);

            quizLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
        } 

    }


    private void showQuestion(int qIndex,boolean review) {
        try {
            JSONObject aQues = QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().getJSONObject(qIndex);
            String quesValue = aQues.getString("Question");
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == -1) {
                String correctAnsStr = aQues.getString("CorrectAnswer");
                correctAns[qIndex] = Integer.parseInt(correctAnsStr);
            }

            question.setText(quesValue.toCharArray(), 0, quesValue.length());
            answers.check(-1);
            answer1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            answer2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            answer3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            answer4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            JSONArray ansList = aQues.getJSONArray("Answers");
            String aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(0).getString("Answer");
            answer1.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(1).getString("Answer");
            answer2.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(2).getString("Answer");
            answer3.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(3).getString("Answer");
            answer4.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            Log.d("",selected[qIndex]+"");
            if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
                answers.check(R.id.a0);
            if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
                answers.check(R.id.a1);
            if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
                answers.check(R.id.a2);
            if (selected[qIndex] == 3)
                answers.check(R.id.a3);

            setScoreTitle();
            if (quesIndex == (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()-1)) 
                next.setEnabled(false);

            if (quesIndex == 0)
                prev.setEnabled(false);

            if (quesIndex > 0)
                prev.setEnabled(true);

            if (quesIndex < (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()-1))
                next.setEnabled(true);


            if (review) {
                Log.d("review",selected[qIndex]+""+correctAns[qIndex]);;    
                if (selected[qIndex] != correctAns[qIndex]) {
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
                        answer1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
                        answer2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
                        answer3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 3)
                        answer4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 0)
                    answer1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 1)
                    answer2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 2)
                    answer3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 3)
                    answer4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
        }
    }


    private OnClickListener finishListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAnswer();
            //Calculate Score
            int score = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<correctAns.length; i++){
                if ((correctAns[i] != -1) && (correctAns[i] == selected[i]))
                    score++;
            }
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuestionActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Score");
            alertDialog.setMessage((score) +" out of " + (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()));

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Retake", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    review = false;
                    quesIndex=0;
                    QuestionActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Review", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    review = true;
                    quesIndex=0;
                    QuestionActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    review = false;
                    finish();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();

        }
    };

    private void setAnswer() {
        if (answer1.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 0;
        if (answer2.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 1;
        if (answer3.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 2;
        if (answer4.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 3;

        Log.d("",Arrays.toString(selected));
        Log.d("",Arrays.toString(correctAns));

    }

    private OnClickListener nextListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAnswer();
            quesIndex++;
            if (quesIndex >= QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length())
                quesIndex = QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length() - 1;

            showQuestion(quesIndex,review);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener prevListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAnswer();
            quesIndex--;
            if (quesIndex < 0)
                quesIndex = 0;

            showQuestion(quesIndex,review);
        }
    };

    private void setScoreTitle() {
        this.setTitle("SciQuiz3     " + (quesIndex+1)+ "/" + QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length());
    }


}
```

**Splash Layout Screen (main.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff0000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:text="Welcome to Quiz" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Question Page layout (question.xml)**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/quizLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:lines="3" android:clickable="false" android:cursorVisible="false">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/answers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/a0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/a3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Prev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.21"
            android:text="&lt;&lt;" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/finish"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.18"
            android:text="Finish" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.23"
            android:text=">>" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

NOW I NEED TO ADD AN INTERMEDIATE MENU PAGE AFTER SPLASH.

Eg: A page with two Buttons "Science" and "Geography"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#6699ff" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:text="SCIENCE QUIZ" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/geob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/indiab"
        android:layout_below="@+id/indiab"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="GEOGRAPHY QUIZ" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I managed to direct splash screen page to this menu page. **I want to load each question set in the same "Question.xml" layout  from the "raw" folder using JSON on clicking two buttons.** 
How to modify it?

Comment: add one object in each ArrayObject to identify type of question, if user select SCIENCE QUIZ then fill questionlist with that object only.

Comment: I need to create separate question sets and load.